# Numpy, sorting based on column twice

Tags: python, numpy

I have data that looks like this:

```
[[ 361   2   2]
 [ 259   4   3]
 [ 361   6   5]
 [ 259   8   5]
...
]
```

In the original data, the first column is a `person id`, the second column is a `test id`, while the third is `mark` (for example).

I want to create a `NumPy` array that sorts like this:

```
[
[score_for_test_id_0_for_person_0, score_for_test_id_1_for_person_0, score_for_test_id_2_for_person_0 ], 
[score_for_test_id_0_for_person_1, score_for_test_id_1_for_person_1, score_for_test_id_2_for_person_1 ]
]
```

The length of the new array will be the amount of persons. Each element of the new array will be as follows:

```
[score_for_test_id_0, score_for_test_id_1, score_for_test_id_n ]
```

I know how to do this in Python, but it would be totally inefficient.

However, I'm not sure how to do this in `NumPy`?

Comment: I suggest you look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: I'm confused about your output.  Can you describe (in words) how you arrived at that output?

Comment: So, each row of the new array represents a person and inside each row is the scores for each of their tests sorted from the test ids smallest to greatest  [score for test 0, score for test 1, score for test 2, .. ect.]

Please let me know if there are any more questions

Comment: I fixed the content of my post, it should be clearer

Comment: is `test_id` you mentioned in the output the same thing with `test type` in the input?

Comment: Yes, it is, they are the same

Comment: Any ideas zhang? Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By computing the sum of personId and normalized testId. We can use this as our sorting key. So we get sorting prioritized by personId, and the testId. The sortKey values will be from personId + (0,1]

```
import numpy as np

data = [[361, 4, 1],
        [259, 3, 2],
        [361, 2, 3],
        [259, 1, 4]]
data = np.array(data)
persons = data[:,0]
testIds = data[:,1]
sortKey = persons + 1.0*testIds / max(testIds)

data = data[np.argsort(sortKey)]

#If this is not the same for everyone this will not be possible with numpy
testsPerPerson = np.count_nonzero(data[:,0][data[:,0] == data[0,0]])

scores = data[:,-1].reshape(testsPerPerson, data.shape[0]/testsPerPerson)
```

Output:

```
In [248]: data # After sorting
Out[248]:
array([[259,   1,   4],
       [259,   3,   2],
       [361,   2,   3],
       [361,   4,   1]])

In [247]: scores
Out[247]:
array([[4, 2],
       [3, 1]])
```

Comment: So it is truly impossible to do this?

Comment: No not at all, just needed to think of a better way to sort. See last edit

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could provide a minimum data set and an expected output, but from your description, if your person and test id's are consecutive integers starting at 0, and you have no repeated person-test pair, you can simply do:

```
people, tests = np.max(data[:, :2], axis=0)
sorted_scores = np.zeros((people, tests))
sorted_scores[data[0], data[1]] = data[2]
```

If they are not consecutive integers, a similar approach can be made to work, with a couple of calls to `np.unique` with `return_inverse=True`.

Comment: Cool! but Im not too familiar with numpy (still learning), how would I implement those calls in?